# Linked server issue when adding existing database to "SQL Server Database Project"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, version-control, sql-server-data-tools

I've got 3 databases located on 3 different servers

Database A and B runs on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 instances

Database C runs on MySQL instance

Database A has queries that query data from database B using linked server

Database B has queries that query data from database A using linked server

Database B has queries that query data from database C using linked server

My goal is to achieve database versioning using SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools).
Every time i try to export bacpac file from A and B, occur errors of linked server.

In VS 2015, i try to import current schema from database A and B, but when i try to build, occur errors of linked server.

Also i tried to use this tutorial: http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/ssdt-how-to-solve-the-circular-references-issue/ in order to build dependencies, but i am not sure if it is the right way to import database schema into VS project and then version it.

My questions are:

**1. Is there any possibility to deal with the linked server issue in SSDT?**
 **2. Can i use VS 2015 to version MySQL databases? What approach can you recommend me?**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the linked servers defined inside the solution? 
i.e. a .sql file for each, set to file type `Build` and containing the creation script with any options set:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver ...;
GO;

EXEC sp_serveroption ...;
GO;
```